# blank plot with matplotlib inside pipenv on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, pipenv

**Short version**

Trying to show a plot via `plt.show()` **inside a `pipenv`** opens a window that is completely white, no errors. Resizing the window makes it completely black. Expecting to see a plot depicting a function `f(x) = x^2` (see code below).

**More info**

Saving a plot with `plt.savefig('tmp.png')` works fine.

Installing `matplotlib` to the system wide python3 via `$ pip3 install matplotlib` causes no issues. The issue only arises when `matplotlib` is installed within a `pipenv` executing the same code (see below).

Versions:

- Mac OS Mojave 10.14.2
- pipenv version 2018.11.26
- matplotlib==3.0.2
- pipenv and system python version 3.7.2

Somewhat surprisingly, I can get it to work on an older Mac running Sierra 10.12.6 with otherwise same versions of pipenv, python, and matplotlib. But I don't think I ever ran into the same issue on that one.

**What I have tried**

1. installed `tcl-tk`: `$ brew install tcl-tk`
2. set backend: `$ echo "backend: TkAgg" >> ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`
3. installed X11 server

**What am I missing?**

At this point I am out of ideas. Any hints as to how to get a plot to show up properly within a `pipenv` is greatly appreciated.

Does this have anything to do with a framework install of python as mentioned in the [matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/faq/osx_framework.html)?

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    plt.figure()
    x = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
    y = x*x

    plt.plot(x, y)
    # plt.savefig("tmp.png")    # works fine
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're still having this problem, I fixed it by installing python as a framework (I installed conda `brew cask install anaconda`. Then add your Anaconda to path: `export PATH=$HOME/anaconda3/bin/:$PATH` via `vim ~/.bash_profile`. I can still engage pipenv with Anaconda.